# Increase font size of text based on slider

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

So my requirement is quite simple. I will have a slider control and a textblock. So whenever the slider is increased or decreased the font size of the Textblock should change. I am able to accomplish this quite simple using MVVM pattern.

My problem is I need to show some text below the slider like small, medium, low. Well I was able to read some articles online that says this can be accomplished using a TickBar. But problem is there is no value changed event with TickBar so that I can trigger changes to the ViewModel.

Can someone give me an idea of accomplishing this using slider. I have read some style on google and heres what it does it displays numbers as soon as the slider changed. Can it be changed to text like small, medium, low. Thanks.

```
<Style
            x:Key="SliderRepeatButton"
            TargetType="RepeatButton">
            <Setter
                Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter
                Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter
                Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="false" />
            <Setter
                Property="Focusable"
                Value="false" />
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="RepeatButton">
                        <Border
                            Background="Transparent" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style
            x:Key="SliderRepeatButton1"
            TargetType="RepeatButton">
            <Setter
                Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter
                Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="RepeatButton">
                        <Border
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Background="YellowGreen"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="YellowGreen"
                            Height="3" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style
            x:Key="SliderThumb"
            TargetType="Thumb">
            <Setter
                Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter
                Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="Thumb">
                        <StackPanel
                            Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Path
                                Data="M 0 0 L 8 0 L 4 6 Z"
                                Stroke="YellowGreen"
                                Margin="-2,0,0,0"
                                StrokeThickness="2"
                                Fill="YellowGreen"></Path>
                            <Line
                                X1="0"
                                Y1="0"
                                X2="0"
                                Y2="7"
                                Stroke="Gray"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                StrokeDashArray="1.5,1.5"></Line>
                            <TextBlock
                                Foreground="Black"
                                Margin="-2,30,0,0"
                                Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Slider}}}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <ControlTemplate
            x:Key="Slider"
            TargetType="Slider">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition
                        Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition
                        Height="Auto"
                        MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
                    <RowDefinition
                        Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TickBar
                    x:Name="TopTick"
                    Fill="LightGray"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Placement="Top"
                    Height="5"
                    Visibility="Visible" />
                <Border
                    BorderBrush="LightGray"
                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"></Border>
                <Border
                    x:Name="TrackBackground"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,-10,0,0"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    Background="Red"
                    Height="3"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    BorderThickness="1" />
                <Track
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    x:Name="PART_Track"
                    Margin="0,-10,0,0">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton
                            Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"
                            Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" />
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb
                            Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}"
                            Margin="0,-20,0,0" />
                    </Track.Thumb>
                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton
                            Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}"
                            Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" />
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                </Track>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="0"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="0,15,0,0"></TextBlock>
                <TickBar
                    x:Name="BottomTick"
                    Fill="LightGray"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Placement="Bottom"
                    Height="4"
                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger
                    Property="TickPlacement"
                    Value="TopLeft">
                    <Setter
                        TargetName="TopTick"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="TickPlacement"
                    Value="BottomRight">
                    <Setter
                        TargetName="BottomTick"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="TickPlacement"
                    Value="Both">
                    <Setter
                        TargetName="TopTick"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter
                        TargetName="BottomTick"
                        Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style
            x:Key="Horizontal_Slider"
            TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter
                Property="Focusable"
                Value="False" />
            <Setter
                Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="true" />
            <Setter
                Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger
                    Property="Orientation"
                    Value="Horizontal">
                    <Setter
                        Property="MinHeight"
                        Value="21" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="MinWidth"
                        Value="104" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource Slider}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want to change `Text` of single `TextBlock` to either `Small` or `Medium` or `Large` during dragging the slider thumb?

Comment: Do you want to change a `TextBlock` control as @Maxim stated, or change the ToolTip of the slider ? If you want to display text, just set the slider to the range of 1-3 and handle the cases in your VM.

Comment: I just want to change the Textblock size based on the slider control. Again the handling ranges are all done in the VM it all works I just want to display a label underneath the Slider like small, medium, large.

Comment: I got a solution for that where I will use a customtickbar and place both the slider and TickBar inside a Stackpanel so that it gives me the look I want. Not sure if that is the optimal way of doing it.